# Install files into Application Support upon first launch

Tags: cocoa, default

My application allows users to create presets and save them as binary files in the `Application support` folder. It would be great if my application started with some predefined presets, but I can't figure out how to setup the application to install this file at first launch.

Have I to put this files into the project and then move them at first launch? Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 3):

We do that in our project - we check if a file exists at the start of the app.

```
    NSString* fileName = @"...";

    NSArray* dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    dbPath = [[dirs objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    // check if DB exist in correct location
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:dbPath error:nil];

    }
```